# How did C. A. Muses revise Thomson's translation of the Septuagint?

Tags: bible-translation, septuagint

Charles Thomson's translation of the Septuagint was published in 1808, and the revision of C. A. Muses was printed in 1954.  What is an overview of the revisions that Muses made to Thomson's original translation?

Comment: Welcome, and nice question! Thanks for contributing. I took the liberty of editing your question a bit, so that it is more easily answerable (we can provide an overview of Muses's revisions, but not an exhaustive list).  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Good question. I bought Thompson's translation but have been a little wary of it as I know it is not as highly thought of as Brenton.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome Nathaniel. I hope someone is able to provide an answer, so that I can advance with my studies.